# C# Client not reciving a message from the server, not sure whats wrong

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

Please tell me whats wrong.  also note iv been trying to debug this so some code might be extra and not needed but shouldn't keep it from working.  I know its the client not ever receiving the message because I used console.write on both sides of it and only the above the socket.read() showed.  I left those two console.write out on this post.

server:

```
class class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, info.Port);
                TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
                serverSocket.Start();
                log.write(">> Listening for Clients\n");
                bool running = true;
                while (running)
                {
                  clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                  newClient client = new newClient(clientSocket,log);
                  Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(client.start));
                  clientThread.Start();
            }
    }
}

class Client
{
        private clientType cType;
        private EndPoint cIP;
        private TcpClient socket;
        private NetworkStream cStream;

        public NetworkStream stream { get { return cStream; } }
        public clientType Type
        {
        get
                {
            return cType;
                }
            set
                {
                    cType = value;
                }
        }
        public EndPoint IP
        {
        get
                {
                    return cIP;
        }   
                set
                {
                    cIP = value;
                }
        }

        public Client(TcpClient clientSocket)
        {
                socket = clientSocket;
                cStream = socket.GetStream();

        }
    }

class newClient
{
    Client client;

    public newClient(tcpClient socket)
    {
        client = new Client(socket);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        loginObj loginRequest = new loginObj();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(memory, loginRequest);
        byte[] tempOutBytes = new byte[10025];
        byte[] outBytes;
        int numOfBytes = memory.read(tempOutBytes,0,tempOutBytes.Length);
        outBytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
        for(int counter = 0; counter < nuOfBytes; counter++)
            outBytes[counter] = tempOutBytes[counter];
        client.stream.Write(outBytes,0,outBytes.Length);
        //Rest of code waits for respond but client never gets the message so rest of code is not needed
    }
}
```

client:

```
class network
{
    private TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();

    public void start()
    {
        NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        byte[] tempInBytes = new byte[10025];
        byte[] inBytes;
        int numOfBytes = stream.Read(tempInBytes,0,tempInBytes.Length);
        inBytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
        for(int counter = 0; counter < numOfBytes; counter++)
            inBytes[counter] = tempInBytes[counter];
        memory.write(inBytes,0,inBytes.Length);
        object msgObj = formatter.Deserialize(memory);
        Type msgType = msgObj.GetType();

        if(msgType == typeof(loginObj))
        {
            console.write("It works");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A common naming convention: class field names start with lower case letter (which you did), then it's associated property is the same name (spelling) but starting with upper case letter. Keeps confusion factor down.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind for next time, any chance you see the error i made?

Answer (score 1):

Server Program

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace Server
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(5000);
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server Started at {0}",DateTime.Now.ToString());
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
                    Thread th = new Thread(ProcessSocket);
                    th.Start(client);
                }

            }
            public static void ProcessSocket(object o)
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)o;
                NetworkStream nws = new NetworkStream(client);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                while(client.Connected)
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Message from {0} is :{1}", client.LocalEndPoint.ToString(), s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Client Program

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient  client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("IP/Hostname", 5000);
            NetworkStream nws = new NetworkStream(client.Client);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nws);
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                Console.Write("your Message:");
                string s=Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(s);
                sw.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent to server");
            }

        }
    }
}
```